# Diferenciar DateTime.Now e DateTime.Now.Date

Tags: c#

Tenho um teste e gostaria de saber quando um atributo recebeu `DateTime.Now` ou `DateTime.Now.Date`, tem como diferenciar quando um atributo recebeu estes valores?

Obs: Podem ser valores variados, o intuito é saber quando uma data é uma data simples (sem horário) e uma data completa (com horário).

Comment: Recebeu que valores?

Comment: Data variáveis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apenas pela linguagem e pelo .NET, não, porque ambos devolvem `DateTime`. O que você pode fazer é intuir isso, conferindo na sua variável se o número de segundos é igual a zero ([que é o que `DateTime.Now.Date` procura fazer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
if (meuDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Aparentemente atribuição veio de DateTime.Now.Date.");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Atribuição veio de DateTime.Now.");
}
```

Vale uma observação que este teste não tem 100% de acurácia, porque nada impede `DateTime.Now` de ser disparado exatamete no segundo zero de um determinado dia, mas isso é um pouco remoto de acontecer.

Comment: Pensei nessa possibilidade do segundo zero também.

Comment: ou `meuDateTime == meuDateTime.Date`, o que parece um pouco estranho secalhar :p

Comment: @BrunoCosta A coisa que deve ser desoladora trabalhar com tempo deve ser a premissa de ter que assegurar quase 0% de falhas.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Pois mas com a minha solução comparo o dia, mês e ano também. na sua só comparo os segundos.

Answer (score 1):

Sim. Em primeiro lugar sugeria utilizar `DateTime.Today` o dia de hoje que é equivalente a `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Por este mesmo motivo basta fazer a seguinte comparação:

```
if(data == data.Date)
```

EDIT: esta comparação também verifica o ano, mês e dia